# Can a class object be created as an lvalue-only?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

A well-known problem with `std::lock_guard` (and its relatives) is that it does not work the way as expected when only a temporary object is created.

For example:

```
std::mutex mtx;

std::lock_guard<std::mutex> {mtx} // temporary object, does not lock the entire scope

std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck{mtx} // correct
```

I tried reference qualifiers to create a replacement that prevents a temporary object from being created (at compile time). The following code is a futile attempt:

```
#include <mutex>

template<typename T>
struct my_lock {
    T &mtx;
    my_lock(T &t) : mtx{t} { lock(); }
    ~my_lock() { unlock(); }

    void lock() & { mtx.lock(); };
    void unlock() & { mtx.unlock(); };
};


std::mutex mtx;

int main()
{
    my_lock<std::mutex> {mtx}; // A 

    my_lock<std::mutex lck{mtx}; // B
}
```

This does not work, so the question becomes:

Is it possible to write the class in such a way that the compiler rejects `A` and accepts `B` ?

Comment: The title makes no sense, an lvalue is an expression category

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you can use `c++17`, you can use `[[nodiscard]]` attribute with factory function.

---

```
class [[nodiscard]] my_lock{
   my_lock()=default;
   friend my_lock lock();
};
[[nodiscard]] my_lock lock(){return {};}

int main(){
    { lock(); } //warning for discard return value
    { auto l = lock();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me reinterpret your question, instead of:

> Is it possible to write the class in such a way that the compiler rejects A and accepts B ?

I'm gonna read this as

> Is it possible for my compiler to reject A and accept B?

Yes, this is possible depending on the compiler without requiring to write your own classes. I'm very familiar with clang, however, similar checks will exist in other compilers or static analysers.

For clang, [`-Wunused-value -Werror`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wunused-value) will do the job. The first activates the warning, the second promotes it to an error.

Personally, I'm in favor to enable all warnings and explicitly disable those you have a reason not to comply to, including documentation on why.

Comment: Interesting point, but in this case it does not catch it as an unused value